# How to concatenate URL and string, and get data from API at click a button using axios in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, api, get, axios, concatenation

this is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Form, Card, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Ceklaporan extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            client: "10018318318anhsajda0skflisjf",
            uniq_id: '',
            data: [],
        }
    }


    notiket() {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://11100011000/bla/?m=api&f=jadjsjf&client_id=djhajdhajdhajc&uniq_id=${this.state.uniq_id}'
        })
            .then((v) => {
                console.log(v.data)
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e.response))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <Form style={{ marginTop: 50, width: '40%' }}>
                        <Form.Group id="uniqid">
                            <Form.Control type="text"
                                placeholder=" Nomor Tiket Laporan"
                                name="uniqid"
                                onChange={(v) => this.setState({
                                    uniq_id: v.target.value,
                                })}
                                value={this.state.uniq_id}
                                required />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button
                            variant="primary"
                            size="sm"
                            onClick={() => this.notiket()}
                            style={{
                                marginTop: 10,
                                marginBottom: 30,
                                width: '30%'
                            }}
                        >Simpan
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <Table striped bordered hover variant="light" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nomor Tiket</th>
                                <th>Tanggal</th>
                                <th>Pengirim</th>
                                <th>Judul</th>
                                <th>Detail</th>
                                <th>Topik</th>
                                <th>Lokasi</th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        
                        
                            {this.state.data.map(data => (
                                <tr key={data.uniq_id}>
                                    <td>{data.uniq_id}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
                <div className="card" >
                    <Card id="tindaklanjut">
                        <Card.Header as="h5" style={{ backgroundColor: '#0CCDA3', fontSize: 21, fontFamily: 'serif', color: 'white' }}>Detail Tindak Lanjut</Card.Header>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <div>                                                                                      

                                {this.state.data.map(data => (
                                    <tr key={data.uniq_id}>
                                        <td>{data.history}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Ceklaporan;





so when the user enters the complaint number previously obtained, when the "SEARCH" button is clicked, the "GET DATA" request from AXIOS to the API will appear in the table provided under the form, while for "FOLLOW-UP DETAIL" will appear on the card below it, the Card is specifically for displaying the "HISTORY" of the report


so my problem is:
1. concatenate URL and UNIQ_ID from the state that is in the function "NOTICET"
2. data cannot be displayed in the table below the form
3. HISTORY cannot be displayed on the card at the bottom of the table


This is the form to input the complaint number:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Use template literal ` not ' for your string concatenation.

Comment: can you give me example ?

Comment: ` http://11100011000/bla/?m=api&f=jadjsjf&client_id=djhajdhajdhajc&uniq_id=${this.state.uniq_id}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the form to input the complaint number:

```
<div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <Form style={{ marginTop: 50, width: '40%' }}>
                        <Form.Group id="uniqid">
                            <Form.Control type="text"
                                placeholder=" Nomor Tiket Laporan"
                                name="uniqid"
                                onChange={(v) => this.setState({
                                    uniq_id: v.target.value,
                                })}
                                value={this.state.uniq_id}
                                required />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button
                            variant="primary"
                            size="sm"
                            onClick={() => this.notiket()}
                            style={{
                                marginTop: 10,
                                marginBottom: 30,
                                width: '30%'
                            }}
                        >Simpan
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </div>
```